# Exoplayer playWhenReady doesn't work Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to create one screen with a video as a background using jetpack compose; I have found the next solution.

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val exoPlayer = remember {
        SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .build().apply {
                val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    context,
                    Util.getUserAgent(context, context.packageName)
                )
                val source = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(
                        MediaItem.Builder().setUri(
                            Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/intro_video_android_19_9.mp4")
                        ).build()
                    )
                this.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ALL
                this.setMediaSource(source)
            }
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { localContext ->
            PlayerView(localContext).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                player?.playWhenReady = true
                controllerHideOnTouch = true
                useController = false
                controllerAutoShow = false
                resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                player?.play()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The problem that faces this solution is that the **playWhenReady** doesn't work, so the screen keeps in black, and the only way to play the video is by interacting with the controllers.

My question is: do you know a way to force the autoplay of the video?

Comment: Try like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977304/3974530

Answer (score 1):

use the  player!!.prepare() before  player!!.playWhenReady = true ,it's working for me

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I changed my approach of using ExoPlayer for this case, and instead, uses VideView that fit perfect for this use case, the final code is this:

```
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { localContext ->
            val uri =
                Uri.parse("android.resource://" + localContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.intro_video_android_19_9)
            val videoView = VideoView(localContext)
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener {
                videoView.start()
            }
            videoView.start()
            videoView
        }
    )
}
```